# Change menuItemLabel color when touch starts

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Hey I can't find an answer to this anywhere. I want to change my menuItemLabel's font colour when touched. By default it scales and animates to be bigger when you first touch it, but how to customize it more? Here is my label and menuitem:

```
//add options label
optionsLabelSettings = Label::createWithTTF("OPTIONS", "fonts/font1.ttf", 140);
optionsLabelSettings->setColor(Color3B(255,255,255));
auto optionsItem = MenuItemLabel::create(optionsLabelSettings, CC_CALLBACK_1(MainMenuScene::GoToOptionsScene, this));
optionsItem->setPosition( Point (visibleSize.width/2  + origin.x, visibleSize.height /2));

//add menu
auto menu = Menu::create(optionsItem, NULL);
menu->setPosition( Point(0,0));
this->addChild(menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change font color, you can insert such method in your handler:

```
void MainMenuScene::GoToOptionsScene(parameters)
{
optionsItem->getLabel()->setColor(Color3B::BLACK); // or any other color
… // your method of switching to another scene
}
```

If you switch to another scene after pressing, it will be ok.
But if you plan to stay on the current scene, this method is not suitable, because you can’t to restore the font color back. In this case better way is using MenuItemImage and creating images for normal and selected states:

```
MenuItemImage *optionsItem = MenuItemImage::create(«normalImage.png», «selectedImage.png», CC_CALLBACK_1(MainMenuScene::GoToOptionsScene, this));
```

Or using ui::Button, if you haven’t images:

```
ui::Button* optionsItem = ui::Button::create();
    optionsItem->setPosition(…);
    optionsItem->setTitleText(«OPTIONS»);
    optionsItem->setTitleFontName("fonts/font1.ttf");
    optionsItem->setTitleFontSize(140);
    optionsItem->setTitleColor(Color3B::WHITE);
    optionsItem->addTouchEventListener([&](Ref* sender, Widget::TouchEventType type){
        switch (type)
        {
            case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::BEGAN:
                this->startPressingGoToOptionsScene();
                break;
            case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::ENDED:
                this->finishPressingGoToOptionsScene();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
    this->addChild(optionsItem);
```

and then in each handler set different button behavior:

```
void MainMenuScene::startPressingGoToOptionsScene(parameters)
{
optionsItem->setTitleColor(Color3B::BLACK);
optionsItem->setTitleText(«…») // change anything else
…
}

void MainMenuScene::finishPressingGoToOptionsScene(parameters)
{
optionsItem->setTitleColor(Color3B::WHITE); // return original font color and other changes
…
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
customise your MenuItemLabel class & Implement following two methods  :-

class ChangedMenuItemLabel : MenuItemLabel
{
bool ChangedMenuItemLabel::initWithLabel(cocos2d::Node *label, const ccMenuCallback &callback)
{
    if (!MenuItemLabel::initWithLabel(label,callback)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
void selected(){
this->setColor("your color");
}
void unselected(){
this->setColor("your color");//or nothing
}
}
```